# How to get name of boolean variable

Tags: java

I have one question?
I have one ArrayList with strings

```
ArrayList<String> ff = new ArrayList<String>();
                ff.add("T1");
                ff.add("T1F1");
                ff.add("T1F2");
                ff.add("T1F3");
```

Now I want to make a list of booleans where the NAME of variables will be the names of ff list, and the value is true.

Something like this to look the list:

```
Boolean T1 = new Boolean(true);
Boolean T1F1 = new Boolean(true);
Boolean T1F2 = new Boolean(true);
Boolean T1F3 = new Boolean(true);
```

And after that how can I get the name of the boolean variable, when it will need me?

Thank you very much

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: How you expect to use that?

Comment: Value and name are different. Tell what you want to do. We will have better approach

Comment: It looks like you want a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)<String, Boolean>

Comment: The only way you can do this is with a `Map<String, Boolean>`. You can't get the name of a variable at runtime, because a value might be assigned to zero or more variables.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a Map?

```
Map<String, Boolean> theMap = new HashMap<>();
theMap.put("T1", true);
theMap.put("T1F1", true);
theMap.put("T1F2", true);
theMap.put("T1F3", true);
```